# EDIT: Edited values in a datatable are not passed as choices in a selectInput()

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a simple shiny app:

```
#ui.r
navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("General",
           sidebarLayout(

             sidebarPanel(
               uiOutput("tex2"),
               uiOutput("book3")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               DT::dataTableOutput("hot3")

             )
           )))
#server.r
  library(shiny)
library(DT)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  output$tex2<-renderUI({
    numericInput("text2","#tests",
                 value = 1,
                 min=1
    )
  })

  output$book3<-renderUI({

    selectInput("bk3", 
              "Change Name", 
              choices=(rt1()[,1]))
  })

  rt1<-reactive({
    data.frame(
      Label=paste("Test",1:input$text2),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  })

  output$hot3 <-DT::renderDataTable(

    rt1(),
    editable = TRUE

  )

}
```

As you can see I have an editable datatable and I pass its label values to the `selectInput()` "Change Name". The problem is that when I edit the Labels in the datatable the values in the `selectInput()` do not change accordingly.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to edit the table directly? Otherwise see here https://rstudio.github.io/DT/#table-editing.
If you want to get the selected row/column/cell see here https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html#selecting-rowscolumnscells

Comment: Thank you for the useful comment. Based on this I modified my initial question. Now I wonder why I cannot pass the edited values.

Comment: It can be done but I'll have to try get back to you next week properly. See this example https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/ - particularly the line "observeEvent(input$x2_cell_edit, {" which observes when an edit takes place. Otherwise there is also rhandsontable - https://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/ or the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you want to do, I think this is not possible with `DT`.

This is possible with [the `D3TableFilter` package](https://github.com/ThomasSiegmund/D3TableFilter) (available on Github only so far). Please run this code and say me if this is indeed what you want to do:

```
library(shiny)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(D3TableFilter) # devtools::install_github("ThomasSiegmund/D3TableFilter")

ui <- navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("General",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               uiOutput("tex2"),
               uiOutput("book3")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               d3tfOutput("hot3")
             )
           )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$tex2<-renderUI({
    numericInput("text2", "#tests", value = 1, min=1)
  })

  rt1 <- reactiveVal(
    data.frame(
      Label = "Test 1",
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  )

  observe({
    if(is.null(input$text2)) return(NULL)
    rt1(
      data.frame(
        Label = paste("Test", 1:input$text2),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    )
  })

  output$book3 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("bk3", "Change Name", choices=rt1()[,1])
  })

  output$hot3 <- renderD3tf({
    # Define table properties. See http://tablefilter.free.fr/doc.php for a complete reference
    tableProps <- list(
      btn_reset = TRUE,
      col_types = c("string", "string") # alphabetic sorting for the row names column
    )

    d3tf(rt1(),
         tableProps = tableProps,
         extensions = list(
           list(name = "sort")
         ),
         showRowNames = TRUE,
         tableStyle = "table table-bordered", 
         edit = TRUE)
  })

  observe({
    if(is.null(input$hot3_edit)) return(NULL);
    edit <- input$hot3_edit;

    isolate({
      # need isolate, otherwise this observer would run twice for each edit
      row <- as.integer(edit$row);
      val <- edit$val;
      dat <- rt1()
      dat[,"Label"][row] <- val
      rt1(dat)
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: For some reason the selectinput "book3" is not displayed in my interface

Comment: @firmo23 Weird, this works for me. Do you launch the app in a browser or in RStudio ? Don't launch it in RStudio, this often causes some problems.

Comment: Stephane is it possible to change the column name "Rownames" to something else?Tnx in advance.

Comment: @firmo23 I've just tried and I didn't manage. So, as a workaround, you can add to the dataframe a new first column with the name you want, and set the option `showRowNames=FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting the answer from [Stéphane Laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100107/st%C3%A9phane-laurent) using `DT` gives the below:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("General",
            sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               uiOutput("tex2"),
               uiOutput("book3")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               DTOutput("hot3")
             )
           )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$tex2<-renderUI({
    numericInput("text2", "#tests", value = 1, min=1)
  })

   rt1 <- reactiveVal(
    data.frame(
      Label = "Test 1",
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  )

  observe({
    if(is.null(input$text2)) return(NULL)
    rt1(
      data.frame(
        Label = paste("Test", 1:input$text2),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    )
  })

  output$book3 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("bk3", "Change Name", choices=rt1()[,1])
  })

  output$hot3 <- renderDT({
    datatable(rt1(), editable = TRUE)
  })

  observe({
    if(is.null(input$hot3_cell_edit)) return(NULL);
    edit <- input$hot3_cell_edit;

    isolate({
      # need isolate, otherwise this observer would run twice for each edit
      row <- as.integer(edit$row);
      val <- edit$value;
      dat <- rt1()
      dat[,"Label"][row] <- val
      rt1(dat)
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```